# getting test class instance in nose test object to sync up with instance in decorated generator target

Tags: python, generator, nose

I've been working on a way to get tests produced from a generator in nose to have descriptions that are customized for the specific iteration being tested.  I have something that works, as long as my generator target method never tries to access `self` from my generator class.  I'm seeing that all my generator target instances have a common test class instance while nose is generating a one-offed instance of the test class for each test run from the generator.  This is resulting in `setUp` being run on each test instance nose creates, but never running on the instance the generator target is bound to (of course, the real problem is that I can't see how to bind the nose-created instance to the generator target).  Here's the code I'm using to try to figure this all out (yes, I know the decorator would probably be better as a callable class, but nose, at least version 1.2.1 that I have, explicitly checks that tests are either functions or methods, so a callable class won't run at all):

```
import inspect

def labelable_yielded_case(case):

    argspec = inspect.getargspec(case)
    if argspec.defaults is not None:
        defaults_list = [''] * (len(argspec.args) - len(argspec.defaults)) + argspec.defaults
    else:
        defaults_list = [''] * len(argspec.args)
    argument_defaults_list = zip(argspec.args, defaults_list)
    case_wrappers = []

    def add_description(wrapper_id, argument_dict):

        case_wrappers[wrapper_id].description = case.__doc__.format(**argument_dict)

    def case_factory(*factory_args, **factory_kwargs):

        def case_wrapper_wrapper():

            wrapper_id = len(case_wrappers)

            def case_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

                args = factory_args + args
                argument_list = []
                for argument in argument_defaults_list:
                    argument_list.append(list(argument))
                for index, value in enumerate(args):
                    argument_list[index][1] = value
                argument_dict = dict(argument_list)
                argument_dict.update(factory_kwargs)
                argument_dict.update(kwargs)
                add_description(wrapper_id, argument_dict)
                return case(*args, **kwargs)

            case_wrappers.append(case_wrapper)
            case_wrapper.__name__ = case.__name__
            return case_wrapper

        return case_wrapper_wrapper()

    return case_factory


class TestTest(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.data = None

    def setUp(self):

        print 'setup', self
        self.data = (1,2,3)

    def test_all(self):

        for index, value in enumerate((1,2,3)):
            yield self.validate_equality(), index, value

    def test_all_again(self):

        for index, value in enumerate((1,2,3)):
            yield self.validate_equality_again, index, value

    @labelable_yielded_case
    def validate_equality(self, index, value):
        '''element {index} equals {value}'''

        print 'test', self
        assert self.data[index] == value, 'expected %d got %d' % (value, self.data[index])

    def validate_equality_again(self, index, value):

        print 'test', self
        assert self.data[index] == value, 'expected %d got %d' % (value, self.data[index])

    validate_equality_again.description = 'again'
```

When run through nose, the `again` tests work just fine, but the set of tests using the decorated generator target all fail because `self.data is None` (because `setUp` is never run because the instance of `TestTest` stored in the closures is not the instances run by nose).  I tried making the decorator an instance member of a base class for `TestTest`, but then nose threw errors about having too few arguments (no `self`) passed to the unbound `labelable_yielded_case`.  Is there any way I can make this work (short of hacking nose), or am I stuck choosing between either not being able to have the yield target be an instance member or not having per-test labeling for each yielded test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it (at least for the case here, though I think I got it for all cases).  I had to fiddle with `case_wrapper_wrapper` and `case_wrapper` to get the factory to return the wrapped cases attached to the correct class, but not bound to any given instance in any way.  I also had another code issue because I was building the argument dict in wrapper wrapper, but then not passing it to the case.  Working code:

```
import inspect

def labelable_yielded_case(case):

    argspec = inspect.getargspec(case)
    if argspec.defaults is not None:
        defaults_list = [''] * (len(argspec.args) - len(argspec.defaults)) + argspec.defaults
    else:
        defaults_list = [''] * len(argspec.args)
    argument_defaults_list = zip(argspec.args, defaults_list)
    case_wrappers = []

    def add_description(wrapper_id, argument_dict):

        case_wrappers[wrapper_id].description = case.__doc__.format(**argument_dict)

    def case_factory(*factory_args, **factory_kwargs):

        def case_wrapper_wrapper():

            wrapper_id = len(case_wrappers)

            def case_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

                argument_list = []
                for argument in argument_defaults_list:
                    argument_list.append(list(argument))
                for index, value in enumerate(args):
                    argument_list[index][1] = value
                argument_dict = dict(argument_list)
                argument_dict.update(kwargs)
                add_description(wrapper_id, argument_dict)
                return case(**argument_dict)

            case_wrappers.append(case_wrapper)
            case_name = case.__name__ + str(wrapper_id)
            case_wrapper.__name__ = case_name
            if factory_args:
                setattr(factory_args[0].__class__, case_name, case_wrapper)
                return getattr(factory_args[0].__class__, case_name)
            else:
                return case_wrapper

        return case_wrapper_wrapper()

    return case_factory


class TestTest(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.data = None

    def setUp(self):

        self.data = (1,2,3)

    def test_all(self):

        for index, value in enumerate((1,2,3)):
            yield self.validate_equality(), index, value

    @labelable_yielded_case
    def validate_equality(self, index, value):
        '''element {index} equals {value}'''

        assert self.data[index] == value, 'expected %d got %d' % (value, self.data[index])
```